# NestJs: TypeError: Class constructor OmitTypeClass on a Dto

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

Im having a problem with a simple POST endpoint when nesjs maps a Dto class created with OmitType (it happens with all dtos created this way). This was very strange to me because this endpoint and the others were working fine, maybe its a issue with versions?

I hope that you can help me, thanks!

Error:

```
 TypeError: Class constructor OmitTypeClass cannot be invoked without 'new'
improvein-challenge-nestjs-1  |     at new CreateActorDto (/usr/local/apps/myapp/build/src/features/actor/actors.model.js:65:42)
improvein-challenge-nestjs-1  |     at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/usr/local/apps/myapp/node_modules/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:160:22)
improvein-challenge-nestjs-1  |     at ClassTransformer.plainToInstance (/usr/local/apps/myapp/node_modules/src/ClassTransformer.ts:77:21)
improvein-challenge-nestjs-1  |     at Object.plainToClass (/usr/local/apps/myapp/node_modules/src/index.ts:71:27)
improvein-challenge-nestjs-1  |     at ValidationPipe.transform (/usr/local/apps/myapp/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js:60:39)
improvein-challenge-nestjs-1  |     at /usr/local/apps/myapp/node_modules/@nestjs/core/pipes/pipes-consumer.js:16:33
improvein-challenge-nestjs-1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

actors.controller

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Headers,
  HttpStatus,
  Logger,
  Post,
  UseGuards,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  ApiBearerAuth,
  ApiBody,
  ApiConflictResponse,
  ApiCreatedResponse,
  ApiExtraModels,
  ApiTags,
  ApiUnauthorizedResponse,
  getSchemaPath,
} from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { ActorsService } from './actors.service';
import { CreateActorDto, CreateActorResponse } from './actors.model';
import { Actor } from './actor.entity';
import BaseResponse from '../../models/base.response.model';
import BaseExceptionResponse from '../../models/base.exception.response.model';
import { ApiTagsEnum } from '../../enums/api.tags.enum';

@Controller('actors')
export class ActorsController {
  constructor(private readonly actorsService: ActorsService) {}

  @ApiExtraModels(BaseResponse, CreateActorResponse)
  @ApiCreatedResponse({
    schema: {
      allOf: [
        { $ref: getSchemaPath(BaseResponse) },
        {
          properties: {
            content: {
              type: 'array',
              items: { $ref: getSchemaPath(CreateActorResponse) },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    description: 'Actors',
  })
  @ApiUnauthorizedResponse({
    type: BaseExceptionResponse,
    description: 'Unauthorized',
  })
  @ApiConflictResponse({
    type: BaseExceptionResponse,
    description: 'Duplicate actor name',
  })
  @ApiBearerAuth('access-token')
  @ApiTags(ApiTagsEnum.ACTORS)
  @ApiBody({ type: CreateActorDto })
  //@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @Post()
  async createActor(
    @Headers() headers,
    @Body() payload: CreateActorDto,
  ): Promise<BaseResponse<CreateActorResponse>> {
    const response: Actor = await this.actorsService.createActor(payload);
    Logger.log(response);
    return new BaseResponse(
      HttpStatus.CREATED,
      'Actor',
      new CreateActorResponse(response),
    );
  }
}
```

actors.model

```
import { ApiProperty, OmitType } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsNotEmpty, IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { Actor } from './actor.entity';

export class BaseActor {
  @ApiProperty()
  id: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: 'string',
    required: false,
    example: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  birthDate: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty({ type: 'string', minLength: 1, required: true })
  name: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty({ type: 'string', minLength: 1, required: false })
  nationality?: string;
}
export class CreateActorDto extends OmitType(BaseActor, ['id']) {}

export class CreateActorResponse extends BaseActor {
  constructor(actor: Actor) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, actor);
  }
}
```

devDependencies:

```
 "devDependencies": {
      "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.3",
      "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.1",
      "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.2",
      "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
      "@types/jest": "29.5.1",
      "@types/node": "^16.11.10",
      "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
      "eslint": "^8.0.1",
      "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
      "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
      "jest": "29.5.0",
      "prettier": "^2.3.2",
      "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
      "supertest": "^6.1.3",
      "ts-jest": "29.1.0",
      "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
      "ts-node": "10.7.0",
      "tsconfig-paths": "4.2.0",
      "typescript": "4.5.2"
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-class-constructor-cannot-be-invoked-without-new

Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new' in TypeScript
The "Class constructor cannot be invoked without new" error occurs when the target property in tsconfig.json is set to lower than es6 or you instantiate a class without the new operator.

To solve the error, set target to es6 and use the new operator when instantiating classes.

The first thing you should do is open your tsconfig.json file and make sure target is set to es6 or more recent.

tsconfig.json

```
"target": "es6",
```